# Run query every 5 minutes

Tags: oracle, scheduled-tasks, oracle-8i

Please find the below query:

```
select count(*) from v$session;
```

This has to be run on the database every 5 minutes. What is the right way to achieve this?

The query has to be run every 5 minutes on the same sql*plus screen. Instead of pressing "/" every minute, I wanted to understand if there is a way.

Database/Server details:

```
SQL> select * from v$version;
Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.4.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> !uname -a
HP-UX ap12121 B.11.11 U 9000/800 ap12121 unlimited-user license
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do what you're asking from within sqlplus, but you can combine a shell script with the "watch" command to achieve something close to what you're looking for:

Create a simple shell script (sessions.sh) to call sqlplus and run the query:

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlplus username/password << EOF
select count(*) from v$session;
EOF
```

Then use the watch command (or HP-UX equivalent, assuming there is one) to execute the script:

```
watch -n 300 sessions.sh
```

Or use cron to schedule the script to run every 5 minutes and direct the output to a log file:

```
crontab:
0/5 * * * * sessions.sh >> sessions.log
```

then tail the log file:

```
tail -f sessions.log
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using a PL/Sql block:

```
DECLARE
    v_sessions NUMBER;
BEGIN
    WHILE true LOOP
        SELECT COUNT (*) INTO v_sessions FROM v$session;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Sessions: ' || v_sessions);
        DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP (300); -- 5 minutes
    END LOOP;
END;
```

If it really is 8i, use `DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP (300)` instead.